# Почему столько соли попадает в хэш?

Tags: php, blowfish

```
echo password_hash('пароль',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['salt'=>'{{соль}}'])
==>                         !
соль   5ef698cd9fe650923ea331c15af3b160
$2y$10$5ef698cd9fe650923ea33uIRU7edHqM0r0E6bTpgi2FnEPp/ODxp.
                            !
соль   nu7BpkWZHSbwzIRVciijBVHZrZdSsSaE
$2y$10$nu7BpkWZHSbwzIRVciijBO1tlhWObqOIC2TJdQJqOfwJqaxBDitNS
                            !
```

и т.д.
Всегда ли это так? Всегда ли это так для соли [a-zA-Z0-9]* ?

Comment: По хорошему соль должна вся попасть в хеш иначе построить такой же хеш при проверке пароля будет невозможно. Видимо в алгоритме есть ограничение на максимальную длину и он ее обрезает под эту длину. И передаваемое значение он не пытается воспринимать как шестнадцеричное а просто как набор байт берет

Comment: т.е. мы просто берем и делаем salt. hash(pass)? Но ведь соль должна тоже хешироваться вместе с паролем, иначе какой смысл? Например hash(salt . pass) или hash( salt . hash(pass) и так далее..  Если ее просто приставлять спереди, то чем она помешает взломщику?

Comment: Соль ведь - это как приватный ключ..

Comment: Соль конечно хешируется вместе с паролем, но и пишется в начало хеша, что бы когда пароль будут проверять функция знала с какой солью делать хеш

Comment: А взломщик по вашему тупее этой функции и не знает|догадается что это соль, не зная которой ему было бы гораздо сложнее сбрутить хэш?

Comment: Просто не пойму, как может защитить пароль соль, которую знает злоумышленник( Всё равно что закрывать дверь на ключ и вешать около звонка на гвоздик в надежде что воры не додумаются что это ключ от этой двери

Comment: Не зная соль программа просто не сможет построить хеш пароля когда он понадобится, а где она ее возьмет ? Соль придумана как раз против того, что бы нельзя было за разумное время подобрать пароль. Без соли Ева может просто хранить базу уже шифрованных паролей. А так Еве надо шифровать все пароли подряд с этой конкретной солью, а операция шифрования занимает довольно много ресурсов.

Comment: Да, но зачем её хранить прямо в хеше? Смысл от этого теряется. Соль придумана как раз против того, что бы нельзя было за разумное время подобрать пароль, не зная соли. (Также имеет место быть разные варианты применения соли,но зная соль и пароль, это не сложно подобрать за обозримое время) Имхо тупо захардкодить соль и то надежнее, хоть она и будет одинаковая для всех паролей, но хотя бы до неё не так легко будет добраться атакующему

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что если Ева добралась до файла паролей, то она не доберется при этом до соли ? А пароль и при знании соли нельзя подобрать за разумное время. если он не 123 конечно. Попробуйте выполнить вот этот код что сверху 1000 раз и посмотрите сколько это замет времени. Берем среднюю длину пароля 6 символов. значащих бит в символе примерно 6 (лат-символы) итого 36 бит - для перебора всех 6 символьных паролей нам надо 2^36=всего 68 миллиардов операций шифрования. При выполнении операции шифрования 1ms (а она дольше) нам надо всего 795 дней

Comment: а на счет 1ms  я сильно погорячился, я попробовал, примерно 10 операций шифрования в секунду. Так что 6 байтын пароли на 1 машине можно подобрать за 217 лет. Ну или за год на 217 машинах

Comment: http://forum.antichat.ru/forums/76/

Comment: ваши расчеты и для простого md5 выдадут тонну времени, тогда как 50% реальных паролей вы можете получить онлайн за время одного http-запроса.

Comment: Ну так эти пароли и без хешей отлично подбираются обычным брутом зачем вообще хеши откуда то доставать. В общем смысл в том, что прятать соль нет никакого смысла. И для нормальных паролей лучше когда она своя для каждого отдельного пароля. А слабые пароли отлично ломаются вне зависимости от доступности соли

Comment: И кстати, вы не забывайте, что это просто функция которую вы вызваете и которая дает вам некий хеш. Какое вы бы предложили решение, куда она должна сохранять секретную соль не зависимо от вас ? Формат хешей документирован, где соль известно, никто не мешает вашему приложению сохранить соль  в каком нибудь секретном месте, а в базе паролей только правую часть хеша. В общем то вся безопасность на приложении. А если не хотите разбирать строку хеша - никто не мешает добавить к паролю свою ключевую последовательность перед шифрованием

Answer (score 1):

[wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)

> В криптографии соль (модификатор) — это строка случайных данных, которая подается на вход хеш-функции вместе с исходными данными. Используется для удлинения строки пароля, что осложняет восстановление **группы исходных паролей** за один проход полного перебора или с помощью предварительно построенных радужных таблиц. При этом соль не защищает от полного перебора **каждого пароля в отдельности**.

Кроме того, соль и приватный ключ - концептуально разные понятия.